# Subsequent images not hiding jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a small test script which is supposed to hide images on button click, however it is only hiding the first image (of 3) and then stops.

The code is below

```
HTML


    <button id="hide">Make Images Disappear</button>
    <button id="show">Make Images Appear</button>
    <img class="img" src="img/puppy1.jpeg">
    <img class="img" src="img/puppy2.jpeg">
    <img class="img" src="img/puppy3.jpeg">

jQuery

    $(function() {
   $('#hide').on('click',  function() {
     $('img').first().hide('slow'), function hideNextOne() {
       $(this).next('img').hide('slow', hideNextOne);
     }
});
```

There are no errors in console, it just hides the first image and then stops although the hideNextOne function is called. There are no ids just identical image elements in html.

??

Comment: @ScottMarcus that would cause all of the images to hide at the same time. OP, could you please post your html?

Comment: Please add the relevant  HTML and CSS to your question so we can have a running example of your issue and provide a running solution.

Answer (score 0):

You say that you don't see any errors in the console, but when I try your code I clearly get this:

```
Error: {
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 23,
  "colno": 3
}
```

You just need to fix your syntax. Properly formatting your code with indentation makes this much more obvious to spot.

You are not closing your `.on()` or `.hide()` method calls correctly and you are not passing the callback function `hideNextOne` as the second argument to the `.hide()` method correctly.

```js
$(function() {

   $('#hide').on('click',  function() {

     // The callback function for .hide() needs to be passed as a parameter
     // to the .hide() method, not supplied after it
     $('img').first().hide('slow', function hideNextOne() {
       $(this).next('img').hide('slow', hideNextOne);
     });  // <-- Closing of the .hide() call was not correct!
     
   });  // <-- Closing of the .on() call was missing!

});
```

```css
img { width:50px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<img src="https://thumbs-prod.si-cdn.com/iF96tb3cgn8IR9aDBJBd7-hDnBQ=/800x600/filters:no_upscale()/https://public-media.smithsonianmag.com/filer/Design-Decoded-Smiley-Face-631%20copy.jpg">
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/43/7b/9b/437b9bbf3fde6d6a331b52bf6c422850--sad-faces-happy-faces.jpg">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e0/SNice.svg/1200px-SNice.svg.png">
<img src="http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/130000/velka/clip-art-smiley-face.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

You had some formatting errors which made your script fail.
You can do it like this and I think it's easier to read as well.

```js
function hideNextOne() {
  $(this).next('img').hide('slow', hideNextOne);
}

$('#hide').on('click', function() {
  $('img').first().hide('slow', hideNextOne);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img alt="image1"/>
<img alt="image2"/>
<img alt="image3"/>
<button id="hide">hide</button>
```

Comment: But, that doesn't address the actual question that the OP asked.